# Team bot loaded via App Catalog blocks all links for non-admins

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Team bots loaded through the App Catalog (not side-loaded) blocks all links for non-admin users

This card action is disabled because KenBot has been blocked by your administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to talk to your tenant administrator to unblock it.